# JQuery Inline text shifts

Tags: html, submit, css

I have a submit button that on click, jquery checks if anything has been selected. If not then it does show() on an error message. Here's the html:

```
<p id="error_message" style="display:inline">dfd</p><input type="submit" class="button" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
```

At the beginning the message is hidden, but then revealed if the user clicks submit without selecting an option. The problem is, the displaying on my text shifts my submit button. This is what the submit looks like without the message:
[image: Not shifted]

And here's what it looks like after the message is displayed:
[image: Shifted]

As you can see, the submit button moves to the right. I have to display inline if I want both the error message and submit to appear on the same line but how do I prevent any movement? Thanks

Comment: Try the following CSS: `#error_message { position: absolute; }`.

Comment: How do you hide the text? Using `display: none` or `visibility: hidden`? Because `display: none` will actually cause it to take up no space, while `visibility: hidden` will still take up space, just be invisible.

Comment: Make sure you've cleared all possible browser specific padding and margins on the <p> element by explicitly defining padding:0; or whatever you want it to be and margin:0; or whatever. Also incredibly bad practice to mix HTML and CSS. CSS should go in <head>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you set the button to `float:right;` it stays on the right end of its container, until content from left div forces it to drop to next row.

so html:

```
<div class='container'>
    <p id='error_message' style='display:inline;float:left;' >dfd </p>
    <input type='submit' style='float:right;' name='submit'>
</div>
```

Comment: that didn't really work, now the button starts off somewhere far away

Comment: ofcourse you have to apply proper css for `.container` also, like width etc

Answer (score 0):

set the position of the button to absolute , OR set the width of the error-message to something fixed